# How to combine sed to search one pattern and delete multiple pattern

Tags: xml, unix, sed

I have an xml file in which I need to uncomment one line.
I am doing this through sed command.

```
<!-- <file file="${result.file}"/>   -->
```

I use the commands

```
sed -i '/file="${result.file}/s/<!--//' file.xml
sed -i '/file="${result.file}/s/-->//' file.xml
```

This works but I was thinking how do i combine these commands and replace with one sed command only.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
sed 's#<!-- \(<file file="${result.file}"/>\) -->#\1#' file
```

I'm capturing the comment's content into a capturing group. In the replacement pattern I'm just outputting the contents of that matching group and omit the comment-start, comment-end

Comment: But this is the more efficient solution. Good luck to all.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @MohitArora Ups, sorry. I was missing to escape the `/` in the xml tag. Probably `#` is a better delimiter in this case. Changed that.

Answer (score 1):

you can chain multiple `sed` commands, separated by `;` char. So you can rewrite your Q as

```
sed -i '/file="${result.file}/s/<!--// ; /file="${result.file}/s/-->//' file.xml
```

IHTH